# Show that the quotient space $X^*$ is locally Hausdorff, but not Hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be two disjoint copies of $\mathbb{R}$, that is say $X = (\{a\} \times \mathbb{R}) \cup (\{b\} \times \mathbb{R})$ for real numbers $a<b$ and consider X as a subspace of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. Define an equivalence relation by $a \times t \sim b \times t$ for all $t \neq 0$. Show that the quotient space $X^{*}$ determined by this equivalence relation is locally Hausdorff, but not Hausdorff.

Definition of Locally Hausdorff: For any $x$ in $X$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U$, with the subspace topology, is Hausdorff.

Comment: Well we know all open subsets of X* are not necessairly disjoint. I just can't find a way to prove that their intersections are nonempty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: $X^*$ is *almost* homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$; there is exactly one pair of points in $X^*$ that cannot be separated by disjoint open sets, and knowing that should make the pair easy to find.

Comment: Is the pair when a and b are equal?

Comment: @KangHoonYou: I don’t know what you mean: $a$ and $b$ **aren’t** equal.

Comment: Is the pair (a,0) and (b,0)?

Comment: @KangHoonYou: Yes, it is. Can you see why they don’t have disjoint nbhds?

Comment: Yes, is it because these points are not part of the equivalence class?

Comment: @KangHoonYou: I’m not sure what you mean by that. What you need to do is show that if $U$ is an open nbhd of $\langle a,0\rangle$, and $V$ is an open nbhd of $\langle b,0\rangle$, then there is an equivalence class $\{\langle a,x\rangle,\langle b,x\rangle\}\in U\cap V$.